How to use multiple ports on the same server for a single domain using nginx and SSL
I am using Godaddy as my domain registrar and  created a <subdomain_name> which is linked to my servers IP address on Digital Ocean. I am also using Let's encrypt to get SSL certificates and nginx as reverse proxy. Below is my nginx conf. file that I am using:
server {
        listen 443 http2 ssl;
        server_name <subdomain_name>;

        #Logging
        access_log /var/log/nginx/<subdomain_name>.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/<subdomain_name>.error.log;


        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                root /var/www/html/test; # Temp for generating letsencrypt
                default_type text/plain;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                #Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken” error.

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:3001 http://<subdomain_name>/;

                #Required for new HTTP-based CLI

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
        }

        # SSL configuration
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<subdomain_name>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<subdomain_name>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
        if ($host = <subdomain_name>) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        server_name <subdomain_name>;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

Setup:
I am running multiple applications that are listening on different ports with some applications being dependent on each other.
Example:
http://<subdomain_name>:3001 -> being a nginx application angular frontend application
http://<subdomain_name>:3002 -> an API that provides http://<subdomain_name>:3001 with the necessary data
http://<subdomain_name>:3003 -> another service

Problem:
When I run the domains without ssl using just plain http like http://<subdomain_name>:3001, http://<subdomain_name>:3002, http://<subdomain_name>:3003 then they work fine.
However when I try to run it in https, then the following cant be accessed:
https://<subdomain_name>:3002, https://<subdomain_name>:3003

The browser says:
This website cannot provide a secure connection <subdomain_name> has sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Only https://<subdomain_name>:3001 works, as it is being redirected because that is what I indicated in my nginx.conf file. However I do get a console error that says
POST https://<subdomain_name>:3002/graphql net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

The problem is that https://<subdomain_name>:3002  throws an error that it is not able to supply the data because it cant make a post request due to it not being a secure ssl connection.
Expected outcome:
I played around with the nginx config by adding different server blocks for the different services but I cant get it to work.
I want that the following will work with https as well:
http://<subdomain_name>:3001    
http://<subdomain_name>:3002
http://<subdomain_name>:3003

Also, I want that service https://<subdomain_name>:3002 is able to provide data to https://<subdomain_name>:3001 by getting rid of this error.
POST https://<subdomain_name>:3002/graphql net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Each server/service that listens on a port needs to be configured with a TLS certificate before it will support HTTPS. Supporting HTTPS on the default port for https, 443, does not enable https on for example port  3001. In general you cannot support both clear text http and TLS encrypted https on the same port either.

Another thing you should consider is to put everything on standard ports 80/443. It makes no sense to use non-standard ports. Different web apps can bind to different domain names (www.yoursite.com, api.yoursite.com, etc) or different path prefix (yoursite.com/api for example). That's exactly why reverse proxys like nginx are popular.
